# Javascript/PHP Interpret 64 bit integer as float

Tags: javascript, php

I have a 64 bit integer that I would like to interpret as a float.  I can do this interpretation in either PHP or javascript, so any potential solutions can pick their language of choice.

I don't mean I want to re-assign something like 4 to 4.0.

I have the follow 8 bytes of data:

Dec (int): 4619191942746344941

Dec (float): 6.6666000000000000

Hex: 401AAA9930BE0DED

I have 4619191942746344941 stored in a variable in my javascript/php code. How do I convert this to 6.6666000000000000?

Comment: What is the relation of this numbers?

Comment: It's not "float" but *double*. Useful links: http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=401AAA9930BE0DED http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format So it's not that hard to just take the wikipedia page and write converter yourself

Comment: @sectus: they are various representations of raw IEEE754 double precision number

Comment: The two different numbers are the same 8 bytes of data, just one is in interpreted as an integer, the other is interpreted as a float.

Comment: *How* is this value "encoded"? (And how/why is accessed as a non-double?)

Comment: @user2864740: IEEE754

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using [pack](http://php.net/pack)

```
//$number = 4619191942746344941;
$pack = pack('H*', '401AAA9930BE0DED');
$pack = strrev($pack);
var_dump(unpack('d', $pack)); // 6.6666
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/RCift)

As function

```
function getFloatFromInteger($integer)
    {
    $hex = dechex($integer);
    $pack = pack('H*', $hex);
    $pack = strrev($pack);
    $result = unpack('d', $pack);
    return $result[1];
    }

var_dump(getFloatFromInteger(4619191942746344941));
```

P.S. There is exists implementation of [pack function on js](http://phpjs.org/functions/pack/).

Comment: Hah, you the man!  Thanks!  If you are still around, I have one last little question.  I have the above code in a function and I am trying to return the 6.666 number, do you have any thoughts on how I might do that as var_dump has no return?

Comment: @PumpkinPie , function added.

Comment: DO you have any thoughts as to why this would not work on a 32-bit machine?

Comment: @PumpkinPie, you cannot store 64 bit numbers as integer in php on 32-bit machine.

Comment: Is there an easy way to cast this as a long or do I need to come up with a more creative solution?

Comment: @PumpkinPie , you could avoid using integer number by using hex only.

Comment: I split my 64 bit into two 32 bit integers and re-wrote your function.  Works Awesome.  Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: @PumpkinPie , i'm glad to hear it. : )